# How I make an addition of two numbers of 32 bits in Assembly using ADC?

Tags: assembly, 32-bit, addition, carryflag

How I make an addition of two numbers of 32 bits in Assembly using ADC?

Comment: Which bitness is the processor?

Comment: I need to Add two numbers in assembly using debug, the program must accept 32 bits.

Comment: Please give an example of this operation.

Comment: which architecture? there's not only a single one you know?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an 8 bit processor with ld, st, adc and add and index registers X & Y which point to the values to be added, result replaces *X:

```
ld 3,X
add 3,Y   ; The first add is without carry
st 3,X
ld 2,X
adc 2,Y   ; subsequent adds propagate carry.
st 2,X
ld 1,X
adc 1,Y
st 1,X
ld 0,X
adc 0,Y
st 0,X
```

Answer (score 0):

`ADC` stands for "ADd with Carry", in fact it is like add two values and add again the value of the carry flag:

```
adc eax,ebx
```

is like:

```
add eax, ebx
add eax, cf
```

or:

```
add eax, ebx
jnc dont_add
inc eax

dont_add:
...
```